# Search template page not Found

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am trying to implement search in my project so that users can search for anything with ease but I keep getting **Page not Found error**.The errors seems like it's coming from my urls.py but I don't know where exactly.

Below are my codes

urls.py

```
from .import views

app_name = 'app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_category'),
    path('search/', views.search_list, name='search_list'),
    path('<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_details, name='product_details'),
  ]
```

views.py

```
from .models import Category, Product
from cart.forms import CartAddProductForm
from django.db.models import Q

# Create your views here.
def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
  category = None
  categories = Category.objects.all()  
  products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
  if category_slug:
    category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    products = products.filter(category=category)
  return render(request, 'products/list.html', {'category': category, 'categories': categories, 'products': products})
  
def product_details(request, id, slug):
   product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
   cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
   return render(request, 'products/detail.html',  {'product': product, 'cart_product_form': cart_product_form})

def search_list(request):
  search_post = request.GET.get('q')
  search_query = Product.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search_post) | Q(category__name__icontains=search_post))
  return render(request, 'products/search.html', {'search_post': search_post, 'search_query': search_query, 'category': category, 'categories': categories})
```

Comment: Kindly, show the console logs.

Answer (score 1):

The url resolver returns the first pattern that matches the incoming path.

The `product_list_category` pattern matches `search/` so `search_list` is never resolved, put the `search_list` pattern before `product_list_category`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('search/', views.search_list, name='search_list'),
    path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_category'),
    ...
  ]
```